# OS to install on a Lenovo IdeaPad A1?

Tags: operating-system, tablet, arm

I bought a [Lenovo IdeaPad A1](http://www.gsmarena.com/lenovo_ideapad_a1-4442.php) (1st generation) in 2012 and I was wondering if it's possible to use [Ubuntu Mobile/Touch](https://www.ubuntu.com/mobile), [Tizen](https://www.tizen.org/), [Sailfish](https://sailfishos.org/) or some other OS on it?

Specs overview:

- Model: Lenovo IdeaPad A1-07 (VD21DGE)
- OS: Android 4.4, rooted
- Screen: 7"
- Processor: ARM Cortex A8
- Memory: 16GB
- RAM: 512MB, LPDDR2 SDRAM
- MicroSD: Supported

Comment: Asking which OS are supported isn’t on-topic here. You could [edit] your question to add which features you’d like to have / what you want to use the tablet for -- then you might get recommendations based on your use case.